# Content doesn't center when change size of text in textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield, textstyle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6lpJ.png)

In the first textfield, I set the size is 16 and everything is OK
But in the second textfield, I set the size if 30 and the content is not center

This is my code:

```
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 1,
  scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  validator: validator,
  readOnly: readOnly ?? false,
  onChanged: onChanged,
  controller: controller,
  obscureText: obscureText ?? false,
  keyboardType: keyBoardType,
  // cursorHeight:  GeneralHelper.scale(context: context,height: obscureText == true ?30:17),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: GeneralHelper.scale(
      context: context,
      // height: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context,height:17),
      **height: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context,height: obscureText == true ?30:17),**
      // height: 17,
    ),
  ),
```

I have post an image above, and above code is TextFormFieldRounded, I used it at:

```
TextFormFieldRounded(
  radius: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context, height: 39.5),
  controller: txtPhoneNumber,
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    color: const Color(0xFF81C59E),
    fontSize:
    GeneralHelper.scale(context: context, height: 16),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  ),
  elevation: 0,
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE3F4E1),
  borderSize: BorderSide(
      width: 0.5,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
  keyBoardType: TextInputType.phone,
  hintText: 'login_phone_number_hint'.tr,

  onChanged: onChangedTextField,
),
SizedBox(
  height: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context, height: 48),
),


TextFormFieldRounded(
  radius: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context, height: 39.5),
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE3F4E1),
  elevation: 0,
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    color: const Color(0xFF81C59E),
    fontSize:
        GeneralHelper.scale(context: context, height: 16),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  ),
  controller: txtPassword,
  hintText: 'login_password_hint'.tr,
  keyBoardType: TextInputType.text,
  obscureText: !isShowPassword,
  borderSize: BorderSide(
      width: 0.5,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
),
```

I think the problem is cursorHeight, but It's not.

Comment: Please add full code of your TextFormField 's Container, I don't see any height 30 you mentioned here

Comment: it's in height of TextStyle: **height: GeneralHelper.scale(context: context,height: obscureText == true ?30:17),** (I set some condition for height)

Comment: Where is your second textFormField. I am only seeing one.

Comment: I have update my question, use can see it above

Comment: textAlign: TextAlign.center will change the text to center